# accessing variables from executescript function

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, chai

I'm looking to set some data dynamically during testing using browser.executescript. Something like:

```
var x;
browser.executeScript(function () {
  var something = x;
});
```

But x seems to be out of the scope of the function being run. Is there a way for me to pass arguments that will be in the inner scope?

Any help greatly appreciated
C

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass the arguments inside [`arguments`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

> Any arguments provided in addition to the script will be included as
>   script arguments and may be referenced using the arguments object.
>   Arguments may be a boolean, number, string, or webdriver.WebElement.
>   Arrays and objects may also be used as script arguments as long as
>   each item adheres to the types previously mentioned.

```
var x;
browser.executeScript(function (arguments) {
  var something = arguments[0];
}, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @alecxe's answer, if you want more readable code, and you can support es6 this seems like a nice option.
More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```
var my, params, go, here;
browser.executeScript(function ([my, params, go, here]) {
  var something = here;
}, [my, params, go, here]);
```