# Paramater is not passed from parent to child function in javascript for browser.executesript()

Tags: javascript, protractor, arrow-functions, es5-shim

I want to open new tab (am creating a href and clicking)using below code in protractor.

If I hardcode the link text directly inside the `setattributes()`, then it works fine. If i send the `linkname` from calling function, `linkname` throws error as undefined.

How to make the function recognize the `linkname` parameter. I tried arrowing and did not work. Not sure whether I have done right.

```
function addclickhref(linkname) {
    return browser.driver.executeScript(function () {
        (function (link) {
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.setAttribute('href', linkname);
            link.dispatchEvent((function (e) {
                e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
                return e;
            }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))
        }(document.createElement('a')));
    })
}
```

Note: The usual way to open new tab using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> did not work in protractor. So I came to use this workaround.

Comment: When logging `linkname` to console before returning the value, what you see?

Comment: Narrowing down your code, [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqzcbz0/v).

Comment: Inside executeScript() console.log does not logs any value.

Comment: ?? You haven't provided the code for `executeScript` ... [And it seems also logging](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqzcbz0/2/) ..?

Comment: Appears to return expected result at https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqzcbz0/3/

Comment: I checked below answer.It seems executescript has some diff way to send parameter as argument.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502933/accessing-variables-from-executescript-function. Yet i do not understand how to replace this in my code

Comment: executeScript is a selenium method to inject javasript..it is not a fucntion which i have created.This is the full working code. There is no sep method as executescript() as u have showed in result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502933/accessing-variables-from-executescript-function provides the answer - which the OP has linked to in a comment!?!

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question you linked to

```
function addclickhref(linkname) {
    return browser.driver.executeScript(function (arguments) {
        var linkname = arguments[0];
        (function (link) {
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.setAttribute('href', linkname);
            link.dispatchEvent((function (e) {
                e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
                return e;
            }(document.createEvent('MouseEvents'))))
        }(document.createElement('a'))); 
    }, linkname); // added second argument to executeScript
}
```

Comment: Should that parameter be at `.executeScript(function(){}, linkname)` instead of the IIFE?

Comment: it is, I think (so many `)` to deal with :p ) - damn ... hang on

Comment: Note the location of `x` at linked Question, if that is the pattern we are relying on

Comment: yeah, I miscounted the brackets - thanks for the heads up - I knew where it should be, I just didn't put it there ;)

Comment: To be honest, I think this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502933/accessing-variables-from-executescript-function anyway!

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried the code which u have edited using the linked question. It opens a new tab but the url is same as the first tab.It does not take the linkname which i have passed

Comment: it works now.I changes arguments[0] to arguments,var linkname = arguments; arguments[0] took the first character alone from the linkname. After removing the index it works fine.Thank you

Comment: odd, that makes the question you found wrong, I think